# Sentry logging integration prevents sentry events being sent (Python)

Tags: python, logging, sentry

I have a python 3 flask server running through WSGI. I have a config file that is imported by my api code that handles environment variables, and I set up sentry in this file. This is my code which is setup exactly as described in the sentry docs https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/logging/

```
        if sentry_dsn is not None:
            sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
                level=logging.INFO,
                event_level=logging.CRITICAL,
            )

            LOG.debug(f"Initialising sentry for environment {sentry_environment}")
            sentry_sdk.init(
                sentry_dsn,
                environment=sentry_environment,
                integrations=[sentry_logging],
            )
        else:
            LOG.warn("Sentry key not set up")
```

The problem is this does not send any events to sentry, in exception logs or even uncaught exceptions. I know that the DSN is correct because if I set up sentry like this, all uncaught exceptions as well as error and exception logs are sent to my sentry project:

```
        if sentry_dsn is not None:

            LOG.debug("Initialising sentry")
            sentry_sdk.init(sentry_dsn, environment=sentry_environment)
        else:
            LOG.warn("Sentry key not set up")
```

I've tried the setup with the `debug=True` setting in the sentry init and logs confirm that sentry intialises and sets up integrations. But when an event occurs that it should report, there is no log or anything recorded by sentry.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: critical is a very high level. Which level do your exception logs have?

Comment: The logs we want to report are exception level logs, but not error. Worth noting that even if I leave it at error level it still doesn't report anything to sentry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that flask was intercepting the exceptions because the default sentry integrations exclude Flask. This meant that nothing was reaching sentry. I added the flask integration according to sentry docs (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/flask/) and sentry messages were sent as I expected.